# Positioning of the game object after scaling the game background

Tags: corona-sdk

i'm creating a game using Corona SDK i have a map and with ball and some other object moving on this map
and i'm using the ultimate config.lua file for scaling background based on device screen resolution
my problem is that i want to arrange some object on this map but for device resolution i have created specific assets for ex android device with aspect ratio lower than 1.72 so in this assets the map is stretched horizontally or it's became wider than other assets
so in this case when i want to arrange an object on top of this map the result is
that my object didn't set in the right place and that because the map is became shorter than is other design for more explaining when i set myobject.y=100 on a device with aspect ration more than 1.72 it set on the right place but when i do the same thing on device with aspect ratio less than 1.72 my object didn't set on the map
i tried to convert my pixels to inches using device DPI but it's still the same

sorry for my poor english
and thanks for help